# ggplot stacked bar order stacks within bar

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a df that looks as follows:

```
Race                  n    ID
White               7000   A
Black               1200   A
Asian               300    A
Unknown             100    A
Native American      50    A
Alaska Native        20    A
Other                5     A
White                300   B
Black                50    B
Unknown              20    B
Asian                10    B
Other                5     B
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart where the two bars are source A and source B and they are stacked in order of N. When I use this code:

```
ggplot(race_df) +
  aes(x = ID,
      y = n,
      fill = reorder(Race,n)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity")
```

The first bar for A is sorted correctly however the second bar B is not sorted in order of n. Is this because they do not contain all of the same values for race? Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a way round this. Reorder the `interaction` of race and id according to N, and map this to the `group` aesthetic.

```r
ggplot(race_df) +
  aes(x = ID, y = N, fill = reorder(Race, N),
      group = reorder(interaction(Race, ID), N)) +
  geom_col(position = "fill", width = 0.5) +
  scale_fill_brewer("Race", palette = "Set3") +
  scale_y_continuous("Percentage", labels = scales::percent) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 20) +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Note that the bars are now stacked in different orders; each with smallest on top progressing to largest on the bottom of its respective ID. The legend preserves the overall ordering and determines the color of each stacked segment.